# How to aggregate a collection and find min/max values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an "orders" collection which is like this:

```
{ typeID: 1, buyOrder: true, price: 100 },
{ typeID: 1, buyOrder: false, price: 120 },
{ typeID: 1, buyOrder: false, price: 130 },
{ typeID: 1, buyOrder: false, price: 250 },
{ typeID: 2, buyOrder: true, price: 500 },
{ typeID: 2, buyOrder: false, price: 610 },
{ typeID: 2, buyOrder: false, price: 690 },
{ typeID: 2, buyOrder: false, price: 590 }
```

and I want to aggregate this collection and find the best buy/sell price for each typeid.

The result should be:

```
{ typeID: 1, bestBuy: 100, bestSell: 120 }
{ typeID: 2, bestBuy: 500, bestSell: 610 }
```

---

Define bestBuy / bestSell

```
bestBuy  = (buyOrder = true && max price)
bestSell = (buyOrder = false && min price)
```

---

This is what I have so far but I know that its wrong. Any ideas ?

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    { $sort : { typeID : 1 }},
    { $group: 
        { _id: { typeID : "$typeID", buyOrder : "$buyOrder"},
        price: { $max: "$price" },
        }
     },
     { $project:
         { _id: 0,
             typeID: "$_id.typeID",
             price: "$price",
             buyOrder: "$_id.buyOrder",
         }
     }
    ])
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How do you define bestBuy and bestSell?

Comment: forgot to mention that. `bestBuy = (buyOrder = true && max price)` and for `bestSell = (buyOrder = false && min price)`

Comment: http://www.inmongodb.net/2015/11/max-min-avg-with-aggregate-in-mongodb.html 
you will get the best refference of Aggregate framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not yet be aware of the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator which works as a ternary condition. So basically if a condition given a as a first argument is `true` then use the value in the next argument. If the condition evaluates to `false` then use the value in the last condition in the operator.

This turns out to be perfect as you already have an indicator of true or false to determine the field

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "typeID": 1,
        "bestBuy": { "$cond": [
            "$buyOrder",
            "$price",
            null
        ]},
        "bestSell": { "$cond": [
            "$buyOrder",
            null,
            "$price"
        ]}
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$typeID",
        "bestBuy": { "$max": "$bestBuy" },
        "bestSell": { "$min": "$bestSell" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

So the use of [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/) and [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) here can negate the `null` values in the results where the condition was not met.

Comment: This is perfect. I didnt know about `$cond`! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a mapreduce you can achieve this with something like that :

```
var mapFunction1 = function() {
 emit(this.typeID , this.buyOrder, this.price);
};

var reduceFunction1 = function(key, values) {
 reducedValue = { bestBuy: 0, bestSell: 0 };
 for (var idx = 0; idx < values.length; idx++) {
  if(values[idx].buyOrder && reducedValue.bestBuy < values[idx].price) {
   reducedValue.bestBuy = values[idx].price
  }
  if(!values[idx].buyOrder && reducedValue.bestSell > values[idx].price) {
   reducedValue.bestSell = values[idx].price
  }
 }
 return reducedValue;
};

db.orders.mapReduce(
 mapFunction1,
 reduceFunction1,
 { out: "your_result" }
)
```

Hope it helped

Comment: You really should learn the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). Apart from the fact that the native code methods will run considerably faster than `mapReduce` this answer has a general flaw in that processing "large" arrays will come at **considerable** cost. There are more efficient ways of getting a "max" or "min" value from an array. As well, a similar ternary can be applied in the mapper. See my answer, there are links in there as well.

Comment: I agree with Neil. Before ask here I used a mapReduce and my job was done in 120sec. With aggregation fw and Neil's solution is under 20sec. Thanks